# Auxiliary lines (measuring elements) in Chrome DevTools?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

In Firefox DevTools there are auxiliary lines if I hover over any CSS:

[image: Auxiliary lines in Firefox]

Are there settings in Google Chrome to get such auxiliary lines?

Comment: (Dev-tools) **Settings** => **Elements** => Show rulers

Comment: @Kaiido Oh so easy. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Kaiido Reads rather like an answer than a comment... :-)

Answer (score 25):

As Kaiido said in a comment, open the DevTools window and go to Settings → Elements → Show Rulers.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an answer to an older post since things/UI has changed in Chrome Devtools and this is the first post Google provides when searching for rules/lines being shown

Go to Settings -> (first section) Preferences -> Scroll way down to Elements -> Check the checkbox 'Show rulers on hover'.

[image: Screenshot of DevTools with Show rulers on hover]

Answer (score 0):

Click the "Grid" button for the grid element on the "Elements" tab.
https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/css/grid

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).